# Where do you see console.log statements inside a POST request NodeJS express server?

Tags: node.js, express, post, request, console.log

I have an express server in NodeJS. It has a POST request with console.logs inside of it. Where Can I find the console.logs?

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("this appears in the browser");
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log("where do I see this text??");
});

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log("Server started (this text appears in the terminal)");
});
```

I'm running the server from Command Prompt. console.logs that aren't within a request appear in it. Where do the console.logs in the POST request function appear? I ask because I would like to see what's going on with the logic inside a more sophisticated POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the Node.js server directly from cmd, it should start the server and listening to the port specified. Now, when you start to hit the route/s all the console.log o/p to the terminal window not to the browser console window. Check the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at the dropdown menu at top right of the terminal where it says "node". Mine doesn't look like that, so I'll try it tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: You can add the screenshot will check how you can see things on it.

Answer (score 0):

It will appear in the same terminal that you put the server to run.